# Allure + Cucumber - some testcases missing in report

Tags: java, cucumber, allure

We use cucumber (cucumber-java 7.2.3) with allure reporting plugin (allure-cucumber7-jvm 2.17.3) for our tests. unfortunately we get some gaps between executed tests and allure reporting, when we execute a bigger amount of tests.

E.g.:
**Test Execution 1**: we execute 170 tests -> 170 tests are reportet in xml, 170 tests are reported in allure report -> everything works fine

**Test Execution 2:** we execute 614 tests -> 614 Tests are reported in xml, 604 tests are reported in allure report -> 10 Tests are missing in result

we tried to...

- deactivate parallelization
- remove all descriptions and tags to reduce amount of data
- split and merge the tests to scenario outlines

all without success...

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

you can focus missing test cases, these could have common problem, maybe syntax, tag or not executed.

Comment: that was the first idea and so I tried it. But the same tests are running fine within a smaller amount of tests and reported properly. they are only missing if I execute more than 400 tests